# Passing types at run-time to a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to refactor some code but I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way.

Below is a simplified switch where I'm creating an observable collection based on 2 parameters passed to a generic function. The first parameter is always an observable collection and the second is the type of the object stored in the observable collection:

```
switch (csvDataType)
{
  case CsvDataTypeEnum.Supplier:
    dataCollection = ConverterService.ConvertCsvDataToCollection
    <SupplierCollection, Supplier>(csvData);
    break;
  case CsvDataTypeEnum.Currency:
    dataCollection = ConverterService.ConvertCsvDataToCollection
    <CurrencyCollection, Currency>(csvData);
    break;
  case CsvDataTypeEnum.Custom:
    dataCollection = ConverterService.ConvertCsvDataToCollection
    <CustomDataObjectCollection, CustomDataObject>(csvData);
    break;
}
```

Based on the above, I was hoping to refactor the code to something similar to this:

```
ObjectInfo objectInfo = new ObjectInfo(csvDataType);

Type objectType = objectInfo.ObjectType;
Type collectionType = objectInfo.CollectionType;

dataCollection = ConverterService.ConvertCsvDataToCollection
<collectionType, objectType>(csvData);
```

My `ConvertCsvDataToCollection` generic function is defined as follows:

```
public static U ConvertCsvDataToCollection<U, T>(string csvData) 
where U : ObservableCollection<T>
{
....
}
```

I then use an implicit type using `var`:

`var dataCollection = Activator.CreateInstance(collectionType);`

and it create the correct observable collection of the required type but I can't get my generic function to take in the Type collectionType and objectType types as I was hoping for by calling it this way:

```
dataCollection = ConverterService.ConvertCsvDataToCollection
<collectionType, objectType>(csvData);
```

but I get the following error:

`the 'type or namespace name 'collectionType' could not be found. Are you missing a directive or assembly reference'`

for both the collectionType and the objectType parameters I'm passing to my generic function.

Is there a way to achieve this? I know this may have been previously asked in the past but I need clarification as the other similar issue I've read so far are still not addressing my problem, or I've totally missed their points. Sorry if that's the case!

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that.  You need reflection.

Comment: Or Expression Trees. Generic type parameters have to be set at compile time. You can somewhat get around it without reflection or expression trees by passing a `Type` as part of the parameter list, but at that point you're not using generics anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and apologies for being a re-post but I originally struggle understanding the reflection article I had found including the one mentioned above. Once the penny dropped, the rest was easy and it's working great, but most of the samples were explaining a method with a single parameter, so I might post my own answer on the other post and it will hopefully help others.